# How to write func..(for sequels: UIStoryboardSeque, sender: Any?) programmatically

Tags: swift, segue

I have these codes when I use storyboard:

```
 override func prepare (for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == ProfilePhotoViewController.identifier {
      guard let username = usernameTextField.text, let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text else { return }
      
      let profilePhotoVC = segue.destination as! ProfilePhotoViewController
      profilePhotoVC.email = email
      profilePhotoVC.username = username
      profilePhotoVC.password = password
    }
  }
```

How do I write these code if I don't use storyboard and write them programmatically in order to pass the info from current controller to ProfilePhotoViewController?

EDIT:
After doing research I understand that doing this programmatically is through delegate. However, I don't know how I can complete the code:

Need to pass username, email and password from SignUpController ---> profilePhotoViewController

in SignUpController:

```
protocol SignUpControllerDelegate {
     func handleSignUp(//what should I write here?)
}

var delegate: SignUpControllerDelegate?

@objc func handleSignUp() {

//...other code..//

delegate?.handleSignUp(//??)
}
```

In ProfileViewController:

what should I write to receive the username, email and password info from SignUpController?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try like this

```
guard let username = usernameTextField.text, let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text else { return }

let profileVC = ProfilePhotoViewController()
profileVC.email = email
```

Answer (score 2):

We can create a view controller with/without a NIB file.

With NIB, you use `init(nibName: String?, bundle: Bundle?)` method. In this case, `view` will be defined using Interface Builder.

```
// bundle = nil denote the main bundle
let viewController = MyViewController(nibName:"MyViewController", bundle: nil)
```

Also you can define a custom `UIViewController` subclass without a NIB file and implement `loadView()` method.

```
override func loadView() {
    self.view = UIView(...)
}
```

After that, we need to add the view into the view hierarchy.

```
self.view.addSubview(viewController.view);
// or
self.present(viewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
// or if we have UINavigationController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: false)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, after doing some research, I found out that doing programmatically is to through delegate method. Do you know how to do that? I don't want to use storyboard and nib, I want to do it programmatically.